# Possible to show and store top 3 results of Google Search?

Tags: web-scraping, google-search

Is it possible to show and store the results obtained from a Google Search query? The search is performed from the commons-http client, through my webapp. My questions are:

1. Is it permissible?
2. Is it ethical?
3. Is it possible?

I have heard that google changes tags and blocks scrapers. Is it correct? Any other way to do it?

Comment: [5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS)

Comment: After a few hundred requests your IP will be blocked and you'll see something [like this](http://sorry.google.com/sorry/). Is it ethical? No. Is it possible? Yes. Proxies are your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to scrape Google for results - many do. You can use proxies to mask your IP and avoid being blocked.

Make sure you set your user-agent to a browser.

Google [doesn't like this](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS) and provides a [search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/), but it is pretty useless.